# On exit event for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I register an OnExit Event for my Windows Phone 8 app to do some tasks before user exits Application.

I tried using:

```
Application.Current.Exit
```

But Visual Studio says it wont be called for Windows Phone.
Any Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [PhoneApplicationService.Closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.closing%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). In the autogenerated App.xaml.cs you should already have a hooked-up `Application_Closing` handler. However, you should not use it, as:

> If your app is terminated by the operating system while it is not in the foreground, the Closing event will not be raised. Your app can rely on receiving the Deactivated event, but not Closing. For this reason, you should perform all essential cleanup and state maintenance tasks in the Deactivated event handler.

Put your tasks in the auto-generated `Application_Deactivated` method.

Comment: Hi. I am not having any `Application_Closing` handler by default. So I tried registering one with `PhoneApplicationService` but there was no `Closing` event there. So I added one with `PhoneApplicationService.Current`. But now its not getting called. Neither in `PhoneApplicationService.Current.Closing` event nor in `PhoneApplicationService.Current.Launching` event. Help?

Comment: Your App.xaml should have:   <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
      Launching="Application_Launching" 
      Closing="Application_Closing" 
      Activated="Application_Activated" 
      Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
  </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

Comment: Will it be called even if I call `Application.Current.Terminate()` ?

Comment: @PratPor I never used `Terminate`, so you will have to check that yourself. But I would advise you not to exit the application programmatically, but to rely on standard Windows Phone navigation model.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight Application since you didn't state otherwise.

In your App.xaml.cs there should be an Application_Closing() event. You'd want to run these tasks here. Just beware as you only have a few seconds to run code before the OS kills your process.